# Can I replace Prototype with Dojo in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, dojo, prototypejs, replace

Can I replace Prototype with Dojo in Rails 3?

I know I can put jQuery as the javascript library, but I want to know if there is some plugin that replaces Prototype with Dojo.

Thanks!

EDIT:

For those seeking an answer for this question, it seems that the dojo project is developing an extension that replaces prototype's rails.js by dojo's rails.js. The extension is still unstable, but already make its way to DojoX (dojox.rails) in trunk.

http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/browser/dojox/trunk/rails.js

Comment: I'm sure you already know this, but have you considered JQuery?

Comment: Hi, @sscirrus. Yes, I did. I don't like jQuery to build web apps, but only for web sites. It's more of a personal choice, based on that jQuery UI does not have a lot of features like dojo, and I don't like to throw third party code into my client's apps (via plugins). But thanks for the comment :)

Comment: Fair enough! Best of luck Eduardo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using dojox.rails in an application without any problem so far with rails 3.0.7
I still need to assess what will need to be changed considering the upcoming release of rails 3.1

Cheers

Guy

Comment: How stable is dojox.rails right now? Are you using it in production?